# WSM size in VEINS Simulator

Tags: omnet++, veins

In Veins, the size of beacon is set to 336 bits (80 bits for header &  256 bits for beacon length). My questions are: a) Why the size of a beacon is set to 336 bits? b) Which fields actually give us the size of 336 bits ?

Comment: I remember searching for this; if I recall correctly it's based on SAE standards, but I'll see if I can confirm that